# c# - Birthday notifier

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, notify

I am working on a project (simple phonebook) for personal use. I display my contacts in a listview and the contacts are stored in a XML file. It contains contacts' data like name, city, address, birthday etc. Basically, I would like to be notified when it is contact's birthday by the notify icon (balloon).

For example:

```
<People>
  <Person>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <Hometown>Washington</Hometown>
     <Address>231 Main Street</Address>
     <Birthday>130299511993682082</Birthday>
     <Phone>555-555-555</Phone>
     <Email>john@gmail.com</Email>
     <AdditionalInfo>Skype: john.123</AdditionalInfo>
  </Person>
<People>
```

In this case, the notify icon should appear when it's John's birthday. I am completely stuck here, since I have no idea how to do this. Theoretically, it should look for birthdays in the XML file and then compare it to the current date. If it is a match, the notify icon should appear. The problem is I do not know to do this myself.

This is a part of my **private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)**, where I load the contacts into the listview. I thought I could use **p.Birthday** somehow, but the only thing that crosses my mind is if (p.Birthday == DateTime.Now), but this surely is not the proper way of doing things.

```
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string phonebook_path = path + "\\Phonebook\\Contacts.xml";
    if (!File.Exists(phonebook_path))
    {
        XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(phonebook_path, Encoding.UTF8);
        xW.WriteStartElement("People");
        xW.WriteEndElement();
        xW.Close();
    }
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(phonebook_path);
    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
        p.Hometown = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Hometown").InnerText;
        p.Address = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Address").InnerText;
        p.Birthday = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("Birthday").InnerText));
        p.Phone = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText;
        p.Email = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText;
        p.AdditionalInfo = xNode.SelectSingleNode("AdditionalInfo").InnerText;
        people.Add(p);
        listView1.Items.Add(p.Name);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In case you don't have code, you should post your though process/ideas. At stackoverflow, you will have a much higher chance for an answer when you show understanding of the problem. A question like this, asking for a complete solution, is often regarded as too broad to answer.

Comment: OMG, haven't I already posted what I had come up with?! "Theoretically, it should look for birthdays in the XML file and then compare it to the current date. If it is a match, the notify icon should appear. The problem is I do not know to do this myself." And that' where my knowledge stops. If I already had clear plan how to do this, I would certainly not bother you. The only part I cannot do myself is checking whether today's date matches with someone's birthday in my XML file - the rest is "a piece of cake".

Comment: Do you know how to read the XML file?  What format is the Birthday in?  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the dates isn't that hard, but I would suggest that you change your date format to something that can be recognized by `DateTime.Parse(string)` like MM/DD/YY
[msdn article on parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
 Once the date is in a more compatible format, you can use something like

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(p.Birthday.ToString()).Date, DateTime.Now.Date) >= 0)
        {
            //Show a notify box because the person's birthday is later than or equal to  the current date
        }
```

I got that from the [msdn article on comparing dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
As for the notify icon, that's easy. I use this function, which I got from the [msdn article on notify icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private void ShowNotifyIcon(string title, string message, int secondsToShow)
{
    NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon.Icon = this.Icon;
    notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = title;
    notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = message;
    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(secondsToShow * 1000);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, unlike the rest of the guys, you truly helped me! Cheers!